# Failed to resolve dependency for wicket on jenkins and not on local machine

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to build a project with Jenkins, but I get the following error every time I run it. This is really weird as I have never used wicket 6.13.0 as you can see:

```
[INFO] Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/wicket/wicket-auth-roles/6.9.0/wicket-auth-roles-6.9.0.pom (3 KB at 9.3 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.13.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

which results in

```
Failure to find org.apache.wicket:wicket:pom:6.13.0-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of wicketstuff-core-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I can build it locally on my development machines without problems.

It seems that some guy developing wicket-stuff has put there

```
 <wicket.version>6.13.0-SNAPSHOT</wicket.version>
```

for some reason. This version does not exist in central maven repo. But why my local machines can handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your local repository the presence of wicket 6.13.0-SNAPSHOT; maybe, you downloaded it on the past and local machine uses it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. So someone could have removed it from remote repositories in a meantime? Wicketstuff still uses 6.13.0-SNAPSHOT... what to do now? Yes, I could possibly copy this jar into the repository used by Jenkins, but there must be cleaner way... I would have to send this file to every developer...